# How I can check if PDF is damaged with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, multipart

My PHP program generates a PDF using content of multipart request, but some of PDF generated are damaged and could not be repaired, I don't know why?

My Request :

```
var fromData = new FormData();
fromData.append('first_name', last_name);
fromData.append('last_name', first_name);
fromData.append('file', blobFile);
$.ajax({
    url : url_serveur + 'archiver.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : fromData,
    processData: false,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    success : function(code_html, statut){
        if (code_html.status == 1) {
            // delete PDF
        } else {
            // try for second time
        }
    },
    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
        // try for second time
    },
});
```

My PHP program :

```
<?php

function readFromContent($raw_data) {
    $CONTENT = array();
    // Fetch content and determine boundary
    $boundary = substr($raw_data, 0, strpos($raw_data, "\r\n"));

    // Fetch each part
    $parts = array_slice(explode($boundary, $raw_data), 1);
    $data = array();

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        // If this is the last part, break
        if ($part == "--\r\n") break;

        // Separate content from headers
        $part = ltrim($part, "\r\n");
        list($raw_headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $part, 2);

        // Parse the headers list
        $raw_headers = explode("\r\n", $raw_headers);
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($raw_headers as $header) {
            list($name, $value) = explode(':', $header);
            $headers[strtolower($name)] = ltrim($value, ' ');
        }

        // Parse the Content-Disposition to get the field name, etc.
        if (isset($headers['content-disposition'])) {
            $filename = null;
            preg_match(
            '/^(.+); *name="([^"]+)"(; *filename="([^"]+)")?/',
            $headers['content-disposition'],
            $matches
            );
            list(, $type, $name) = $matches;
            isset($matches[4]) and $filename = $matches[4];

            // handle your fields here
            switch ($name) {
                // this is a file upload
                case 'userfile':
                    file_put_contents($filename, $body);
                break;

                // default for all other files is to populate $data
                default:
                    $data[$name] = substr($body, 0, strlen($body) - 2);
                    $CONTENT[$name] = $data[$name];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $CONTENT;
}

$raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$CONTENT  = readFromContent($raw_data);

$file = $CONTENT["file"];
$first_name = htmlentities($CONTENT["first_name"]);
$last_name = htmlentities($CONTENT["last_name"]);
$chemin = "/var/www/files/";
$filename = $first_name.'_'.$last_name.'.pdf';

if(file_exists($chemin)){
    $contrat = file_put_contents($chemin.$filename, $file);
    $filePath = $chemin.$filename;

    if(file_exists($chemin.$filename)){
        // check if file (PDF) generated is damaged
        $message= array ('status'=> 1);
        echo json_encode($message); die();
    }
}
$message= array ('status'=> 0);
echo json_encode($message); die();
```

How I can check if The file (PDF) generated is damaged?

Comment: To check if something is damaged you should describe a criteria when item is damaged. Do you have such criteria?

Comment: There are more than possible ways to mess up a PDF. Most likely, it is that the xref table is incorrect. You might look out for a PDF Validator (for example, PDF-Tools AG has one), which you could take into the workflow.

Comment: In APK the file is not damaged I think that I should use size as criteria, but I search how I can get the message returned by Adobe Acroba when I try to open the file? or how I can check if there is any loss in the multipart request?

Comment: How I can use PDF-Tools AG in my PHP program? there is web service or library to validate PDF?

Comment: Can I use this condition `strpos($CONTENT["file"], 'xref');` because this article [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-pdf-xref-tables-explained/) said that each file PDF contain ''xref" and my PDF damaged don't contrain this word?

Comment: I thnik you are attempting to solve this at the wrong end. You generate PDFs which may be damaged and now you want to find out which ones are. What if your code finds one? Try to generate it again? Perhaps it's better to focus on the *cause* and find out why the PDFs turn out to be damaged in the first place, because that is (or should be) not normal behavior for your PDF generator.

Comment: We have a lot of magasins use the application and the PDFs damaged are generated from one of these magasins using 3 Tablet (three instance in one place), I think it's because a bad network that they have, I would like to reject all bad request who my PHP program recieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the checksum system and it seems work correctly.

By:

- Hashing the pdf file before the execution of the request
- Sending the hash result as parameter in the request
- Hashing once again when reciept the file with php programm
- Comparing between the 2 hashing results, if they are similar the pdf is not damaged, else the pdf is damaged